# Making .id argument show the names of objects after binding a nested list /R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, nested-lists

I am working with a large nested list of tibbles. A previous post already helped me out, but I am stuck at the last step of forming a usable dataframe out of a large nested list.
In this dataframe should be an 'id' column that shows the name a tibble has within the list. I tried `bind.rows(.id='id')` but it discards the names and gives it a numeric index. How can I avoid this?
Here is a minimized version of my problem:
(I am not really sure if the example is precise enough, as I was not able to name each list element, but I hope the idea comes across)

```
a<-tibble (a=numeric(7),
           b=letters[7:1],
           c=integer(length=1))

b<-tibble (a=integer(length=1),
           b=as.numeric(8),
           c=letters[7:1])


c<- tibble(.rows = 2)

A<-list(list(a,b,c))
B<-list(A,list(a,b,c)) 
C<-list(A,B)

riddle<-list(A,B,C)
```

Following is the code that I am running to get my original data in format, but you will see that the id column only gets numeric indexes, for the example, as for my original data

```
rrapply(riddle, condition = function(x) all(dim(x)>0),  
        f =  function(x) 
        {
          # change to unique column names
          names(x) <- make.unique(names(x))
          x %>%  
            # convert all columns to character if there
            # are mismatch in column types in any list elements
            mutate(across(everything(), as.character))
        },      classes = "data.frame", how= "flatten") %>% 
  # bind the flattened list of data.frame/tibbles to single dataset
  bind_rows(.id="id") %>%
  # do the column type conversion 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Pretending that my example would have names for the 12 values of id - How and which command would I need to implement to get the names of the objects as values for the .id column?

Comment: Your `list` is not named.  i.e. if you want output to be named, the list should be named as well, - `A <- list(list(a=a, b = b, c = c))`  Not clear about how you are naming the `B` i.e. `B <- list(A= A, list(a = a, b = b, c = c))` Can you show what the names you are expecting?  Is it `A`, `B`, `C` or `a`, `b`, `c`?

Comment: Or would you like your input to be `A<-list(list(a,b,c)); B <- list(A = A, list(a, b, c)); C <- list(A=A, B = B);
 riddle <- list(A = A, B = B, C = C)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `list` have names, then we may be able to extract and create 'id' with the names of the list

```
library(rrapply)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
A <-list(list(a,b,c))
B <- list(A = A, list(a, b, c))
C <- list(A=A, B = B)
riddle <- list(A = A, B = B, C = C)
```

-testing

```
out <- rrapply(riddle, condition = function(x) all(dim(x)>0),  
        f =  function(x, .xparents) 
        {
          # change to unique column names
          names(x) <- make.unique(names(x))
          x %>%  
        mutate(id =  str_c(setdiff(.xparents, ""), 
             collapse = "_"), .before = 1 ) %>%
            # convert all columns to character if there
            # are mismatch in column types in any list elements
            mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) 
        },      classes = "data.frame", how= "flatten") %>%
    bind_rows() %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 84 × 4
   id        a b     c    
   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>
 1 A_1       0 g     0    
 2 A_1       0 f     0    
 3 A_1       0 e     0    
 4 A_1       0 d     0    
 5 A_1       0 c     0    
 6 A_1       0 b     0    
 7 A_1       0 a     0    
 8 A_1_2     0 8     g    
 9 A_1_2     0 8     f    
10 A_1_2     0 8     e    
# … with 74 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for putting up an answer with my unprecise example @akrun. Your answer works on my original data too! I am courious if it is common practice to work with stringr in that case? I found it quite hard to find any other approach that does this simple task of showing the object names, although it should be a common obstacle people face, while working with nested lists. Am I missing something, or is that really a badly covered area of popular packages like dplyr? Can you recommend any documentation sites for these problems ? Thanks!

Comment: @arnemaa It is just that you `.xparents` is a vector of length > 1.  So to paste them to a single string, we use str_c from string or just `paste` from `base R`.   Regarding your second question, the data is highly nested and you want it in a 2D table, thus we have to use a recursive function (`rrapply`) along with modifications in the data to make it character columns (we use mutate from dplyr.  You can use transform from base R as well)